# Qt Custom Lists

Tags: c++, qt, unity-game-engine

I have recently started to use Qt as it is much more intuitive then using win32, I have been playing around with a bunch of the different widgets, and I wan't to try something more complex, but haven't been able to find anything on the Qt reference or Google related to what I want.

I am trying to do something like the Unity3D Inspector box, I get so far with how I would go, but it doesn't seem like there is something for one of the needed components.

I would have a dockable widget, in this I would have a scrollable area, at this point I am looking to add 'components' to this scrollable area, these components will all be somewhat different, they should have the ability to expand/collapse into a single line (The identifier of the component), and upon expansion should be able to have multiple widgets inside of them, such as labels, checkboxes, other collapsable sections, etc.

I must be improperly wording what I am looking for in google as it doesn't seem like there is anything similar to what I want, but it seems like a common idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 2 solutions:

### *1/ Manual design*

Dock:

```
*---------------QDockWidget---------------*
|                                         |
| *-------------QScrollArea-------------* |
| |                                     | |
| | *--------ExpandableWidget---------* | |
| | |                                 | | |
| | |                                 | | |
| | |                                 | | |
| | *---------------------------------* | |
| | *--------ExpandableWidget---------* | |
| | |                                 | | |
| | |                                 | | |
| | |                                 | | |
| | *---------------------------------* | |
| | *--------ExpandableWidget---------* | |
| | |                                 | | |
| | |                                 | | |
| | |                                 | | |
| | *---------------------------------* | |
| | *--------VerticalSpacer-----------* | |
| |                  |                  | |
| |                  |                  | |
| *-------------------------------------* |
|                                         |
*-----------------------------------------*
```

ExpandableWidget:

`ArrowL` is a `QLabel` containing only the arrow indicating whether the widget is collapsed or extended. You set the custom widget to the input widget you want, for example an int input. You hide this widget when collapsing, and show it when expanding.

```
*------------ExpandableWidget-------------*
|                                         |
| *-------------QVBoxLayout-------------* |
| |                                     | |
| | *-----------QHBoxLayout-----------* | |
| | | *-ArrowL-* *------QLabel------* | | |
| | *---------------------------------* | |
| |                                     | |
| | *---------Custom QWidget----------* | |
| | |                                 | | |
| | *---------------------------------* | |
| |                                     | |
| *-------------------------------------* |
|                                         |
*-----------------------------------------*
```

Advantage: you can entirely control how the dock behaves.
Drawback: you have to implement this hierarchy by yourself, in a global widget, to ensure its consistency.

### *2/ QtPropertyBrower*

[QtPropertyBrowser](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/trees/master/qtpropertybrowser) is part of the now discontinued Qt Solutions ([licence](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3983)). It enables you do to almost what you want in a few code lines.

Comment: It's quite easy after you get used to it, I guess I haven't had much freedom using win32 for so long.